# Can Pigs with saddles mate in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can you mate two pigs with saddles on? I can't seem to get the pigs where I want them when they are far away and I need to ride them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't breed pigs with saddles but you can easily attract pigs by holding carrots (PC) or wheat (Xbox) in your hand.  Breeding unsaddled pigs is as easy as feeding them that food.

Comment: I think you have to use carrots now.

Comment: Yes, you use carrots on pc and wheat on Xbox